Get Error "not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 0)" when using Django EAV 2
from django.contrib import admin

from .models import Product

from eav.forms import BaseDynamicEntityForm

from eav.admin import BaseEntityAdmin

Register your models here.

class ProductAdminForm(BaseDynamicEntityForm):
      model = Product

class ProductAdmin(BaseEntityAdmin):
      form = ProductAdminForm

admin.site.register(Product, ProductAdmin)

Get error:

Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http: //127.0.0.1:8000/admin/shop/product/add/
Django Version: 5.1.1
Exception Type: ValueError
Exception Value:     not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 0)
Exception
Location:   C:\Users\iskander\Desktop\shop\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\forms\widgets.py,
line 772, in _choice_has_empty_value
Raised during:  django.contrib.admin.options.add_view

Error during template rendering

In template C:\Users\iskander\Desktop\shop\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin
\templates\admin\includes\fieldset.html, error at line 25

<div>
16 {% if not line.fields|length == 1 and not field.is_readonly %}{{ field.errors }}{% endif %}
17 <div class="flex-container{% if not line.fields|length == 1 %} fieldBox{% if field.field.name %}    field-{{ field.field.name }}{% endif %}{% if not field.is_readonly and field.errors %} errors{% endif %}{% if field.field.is_hidden %} hidden{% endif %}{% endif %}{% if field.is_checkbox %} checkbox-row{% endif %}">
18 {% if field.is_checkbox %}
19  {{ field.field }}{{ field.label_tag }}
20  {% else %}
21    {{ field.label_tag }}
22     {% if field.is_readonly %}
23       <div class="readonly">{{ field.contents }}</div>
24   {% else %}
25         **{{ field.field }}**
26    {% endif %}
27    {% endif %}
28          </div>
29    {% if field.field.help_text %}
30         <div class="help"{% if field.field.id_for_label %} 
                id="{{ field.field.id_for_label }}_helptext"{% endif %}>
31          <div>{{ field.field.help_text|safe }}</div>
32          </div>
33       {% endif %}
34       </div>
35  {% endfor %}

I tried to install it before, everything worked, but this time it doesn’t work. I’m a beginner, learning django

Change django-eav2 version to 1.6.1

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
